# Генерация двумерного массива со случайными значениями

Tags: массивы, python-3.x, циклы

Пытаюсь сгенерировать двумерный массив и заполнить его случайными значениями. 
Пробовал разными способами, последний из них:

```
import random
m = list()

for i in range(0, 3):
    m.append([int(random.randint(1, 10)) for i in range(1, 3)])
```

Но он какой то "костыльный", что-ли. Какие могут быть еще варианты?

Так же пробовал сделать такую штуку:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):  // чтоб for был от 0 до вводимого "n"
    ...
```

Так не работает. А почему не понимаю.
Пробовал через enumerate - тоже нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать двумерный массив с n строк и m столбцов, заполненый случайными числами от 1 до 10, можно следующим образом:

```
from random import randint
n, m = 3, 3
a = [[randint(1, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
print(a)
```

---

Используя библиотки, это можно сдлеать гораздо проще. Например, с помощью функции [randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) из *numpy*:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=(3, 3))
print(a)
```

[sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.randMatrix):

```
import sympy as sym
a = sym.randMatrix(3, 3, 1, 10)
print(a)
```

---

Следует заметить, что если вы используете библиотеки, то, как правило, получаете не list list'ов, а объект специального класса из библиотеки с кучей дополнительного функционала. Но, если необходимо, всегда есть возможность перевести этот объект в обычный list list'ов.